# How to query an arraylist using Linq that stores dictionaries

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, dictionary, arraylist

The following code reads query results from oracle data reader and stores each record in a dictionary and appends the dictionaries to an array list :

```vb
Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
'loop oracle data records and store them to dictionaries
'append dictionaries to an array list
Dim arr As New ArrayList
While dr.Read
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For count As Integer = 0 To (dr.FieldCount - 1)
        dict.Add(dr.GetName(count), dr(count))
    Next
    arr.Add(dict)
End While
```

How do I write a LINQ query that can be used to retrieve values from the dictionaries stored in the array list? Please help. I've been searching and have not got any good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `ArrayList`, ever. It is there for backwards compatibility but has no usage. I can make answer short - there is no use of LINQ with `ArrayList`. Use generic `List(Of T)` and *LINQ* to search values in it. No need for `Dictionary` either. This is the old style. We used `Dictionary` because it has `key`

I see, you trying to create your table structure but no need for this. First of all, there is `System.Data.DataTable`, which can be queried on client.

Or use this technique

```vb
Public Class User

    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Country As String
End Class

Private Function LoadUsers() As List(Of User)

    Dim uList As New List(Of User)()

    ' Some Code goes here

        While dr.Read()
            Dim u As New User()
            u.Id = dr("Id")
            u.Name = dr("Name")
            u.Email = dr("Email")
            u.Country = dr("Country")
            uList.Add(u) 
       End While
    . . . . . . .
    Return uList

End While
' somewhere in class set member variable
_users = LoadUsers()

' And then you can search for info using LINQ
Public Function FindByCountry(ByVal country As String) As List(Of User)
    Return _users.Where(Function(u) u.Country.Equals(country, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
End
```

The downside of this approach - you need `Find` function for each field. But what if you can pass a function itself. See- you have `Name, email, Country` - all strings. Here what you can do

```vb
Class Client
    Sub SearchStrings(ByVal searchOption String, Byval searchValue As String)

        Dim f As  Func(Of User, boolean)
        If searchOption = "Name" Then 
            f = Function(u as User)(u.Name.Equals(searchValue , Stringcomparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ElseIf searchOption = "Country" Then 
            f = Function(u as User)(u.Country.Equals(searchValue , Stringcomparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ElseIf searchOption = "Email" Then 
            f = Function(u as User)(u.Email.Equals(searchValue , Stringcomparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

        Else
           . . . . 
        End If

    dataGrd.DataSource = myRepository.FindByString(f)

    End Sub
End Class

' In your repository class
public sub FindByString(ByVal f as Func(Of String, Boolean)) As List(Of User)
    _users.Where(f).ToList()
End sub

' use this to search single user
public sub FindByInteger(ByVal f as Func(Of Integer, Boolean)) As User
    _users.SingleOrDefault(f)
End sub
```

The bottom line - drop what you do and use modern and efficient techniques. And above are just couple of them

Comment: Thank You ! I will go ahead and try out your solution/technique. Will let you know how it goes.